# Как правильно оформить вложенные Beginform?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Добрый день, 
сделал такую форму `asp.net mvc 5.2`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
...
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("name", new AjaxOptions {...}
    {
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Добавить" />
    } 

    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" /> 
}
```

однако, на `Добавить` реагирует не вложенная форма ajax, а форма html.
Как можно сделать, что бы формы правильно реагировали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не проблема ASP.NET MVC, это общее ограничение HTML:

[HTML 5 Working Draft:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element)

> 4.10.3 The `form` element
>
> Content model:
>
> Flow content, but with no `form` element descendants.

Вложенные формы - именно тэги `<form>`, генерируемые хелперами BeginForm - нормально работать не будут.

Вам придется поставить вместо внутреннего submit обычную кнопку (button/div/a) - и вручную обработать клик на ней.